# Error executing with JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I followed this tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/section2.html (C implementation) for implementing a simple example of JNI interfacing but I get this error when running the java file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\JNI_examples\example2\Sample1.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1803)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1728)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
        at Sample1.main(Sample1.java:10)
```

I don't know why it's thinking it is AMD 64-bit...

I also tried running with the path of the library:
java -Djava.library.path=. Sample1

But that didn't seem to help any...

I run cl a little differently because of different paths, this is what I run:

```
cl -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\include\win32" -LD Sample1.c -FeSample1.dll
```

Any clue about what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JVM is probably 32-bit, when you've compiled the DLL for 64-bit. The JVM needs libraries compiled to the same architecture as the JVM, with no exceptions. Change your compilation settings to compile a 32-bit DLL and it should work.

IA-32 stands for Intel Architecture 32-bit, which is x86, while AMD 64 relates to x86-64. Intel ended up licensing the AMD stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! However, I can't find any options on cl to force a 32-bit compilation of the dll... Could you tell me how to change those settings? Thanks

Comment: In Visual Studio? I think you need to use the 32-bit version of cl.exe, which should be stored in another directory. There's a batch file which should do this for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s.aspx